# Logic Apps: SFTP connection issue with UserName and Private Key

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am facing the issue with Azure Logic App SFTP connector (username and private key). I am able to connect SFTP using WinSCP and Azure Function but while using the user name and private key in Azure API connections, it is erroring with "The user does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation" in any action accessing the SFTP.

I checked the permissions for folders in SFTP, everything looks fine. I am sure that it is not the issue with permissions.

Any one have idea regarding this.

Regards,
Sidhu

Comment: "body": {
        "status": 401,
        "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.",
        "source": "sftp-logic-cp-australiasoutheast.logic-ase-australiasoutheast.p.azurewebsites.net"
    }